# Getting "LimitReached" and "InternalExecutionError" errors in CodeAnalyzerDFA Report

Tags: apex, managed-package, security-review

I am getting "LimitReached" and "InternalExecutionError" in  "CodeAnalyzerDFA Report" but didn't get how this error occurring and what is the solution for this.

[image]

Can someone please let me know how to resolve these.

Comment: [Maybe related](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-scanner/issues/1336).